# Content inside Twig block not rendering in Shopware plugin template

Tags: twig, shopware

I'm working on a Shopware plugin and facing an issue where none of the content inside a Twig block is being rendered. I have placed various elements inside the block, but they do not appear on the page. However, if I add an element above the block (like a h1), it gets rendered correctly. I have checked the code and followed the documentation, but I'm unable to resolve the problem. I'm seeking assistance in identifying the cause and finding a solution.

Folder Structure:

```
|-administration
  |-src
    |-main.js
    |-module 
      |-m28-jobs
        |-index.js
        |-snippet
          |-de-DE.json
          |-en-GB.json
        |-page
          |-m28-jobs-create
            |-index.js
          |-m28-jobs-detail
            |-index.js
            |-28-jobs-detail.html.twig
            |-m28-jobs-detail.scss
          |-m28-jobs-list
            |-index.js
            |-m28-jobs-list.html.twig
```

The twig file Im having a problem with is the `administration\src\module\m28-jobs\page\m28-jobs-detail\m28-jobs-detail.html.twig`. Heres my Code:

```
<h1>1</h1>
{% block m28_jobs_detail %}
    <h1>2</h1>
    <sw-page class="m28-jobs-detail">
        <h1>3</h1>
        <template slot="smart-bar-actions">
            <h1>4</h1>
            <sw-button variant="primary" :routerLink="{ name: 'm28.jobs.create' }">
                <h1>5</h1>
                {{ $t('jobs.freeProduct.create') }}
                <h1>6</h1>
            </sw-button>
            <h1>7</h1>
        </template>
        <h1>8</h1>
        <template #content>
            <h1>9</h1>
            <h1>10</h1>
            <sw-card>
                <h1>11</h1>
                <sw-text-field
                    :label="'dasas dasd'"
                    :placeholder="'adsa sd'"
                    :helpText="'dasadsadas'"
                    required
                ></sw-text-field>
                <h1>12</h1>
            </sw-card>
            <h1>13</h1>
        </template>
        <h1>14</h1>
    </sw-page>
    <h1>15</h1>
{% endblock %}
<h1>16</h1>
```

Expected Result:
The Contents inside of the block like all of the h1 tags shuld be rendered.

Actual Result:
Only the first h1 tag (1) gets rendered. I also tested this with less h1 tags.

More Code samples:

`m28-jobs-create/index.js`:

```
const { Component, Context } = Shopware;

Component.extend('m28-jobs-create', 'm28-jobs-detail', {
    methods: {
    }
});
```

`m28-jobs-detail/index.js`:

```
import template from './m28-jobs-detail.html.twig';
import './m28-jobs-detail.scss';

const { Component, Data, Mixin, Context } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Data;

Component.register('m28-jobs-detail', {
    template,

    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.$createTitle()
        };
    },

    mixins: [
        Mixin.getByName('notification')
    ],

    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    data() {
        return {
            freeProduct: null,
            isLoading: true,
            repository: null,
            processSuccessCreated: false
        };
    },

    created() {
    },


    computed: {
    },

    methods: {
    }
});
```

`index.js` (of the module):

```
import './page/m28-jobs-list';
import './page/m28-jobs-detail';
import './page/m28-jobs-create';

import deDE from './snippet/de-DE';
import enGB from './snippet/en-GB';

Shopware.Module.register('m28-jobs', {
    // configuration here
    type: 'plugin',
    name: 'ShoppingCartFreeGoals',
    title: 'general.title',
    description: 'Test',
    color: '#ff3d58',

    snippets: {
        'de-DE': deDE,
        'en-GB': enGB
    },

    routes: {
        list: {
            component: 'm28-jobs-list',
            path: 'list'
        },
        create: {
            component: 'm28-jobs-create',
            path: 'create',
            meta: {
                parentPath: 'm28.jobs.list'
            }
        },
        detail: {
            component: 'm28-jobs-detail',
            path: 'detail',
            meta: {
                parentPath: 'm28.jobs.list'
            }
        },
    },

    navigation: [{
        id: 'm28.jobs',
        label: 'general.label',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'm28.jobs.list',
        icon: 'default-device-server',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 0
    }]
});
```

Steps taken so far:

1. Confirmed that the Shopware plugin is installed and activated in the Shopware instance.
2. Verified that the JavaScript and CSS files associated with the template are correctly loaded.
3. Cleared Cashe
4. Ensured that the routing configuration in m28-jobs/index.js matches the route names used in the template file.
5. Reviewed the Shopware documentation for plugin development and followed the recommended practices.
6. Added debug statements and inspected the rendered HTML, but could not find any issues.

Please note that the list route is working.
And yes, im building my Plugin using the command `bin/build-administration.sh`